# Disable credential manager for single application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, networkcredentials, dial-up

I have a C# application that uses the `rasapi32.dll` to create a dial up connection. When I create such a connection under Windows 7, the credentials get stored in the `credential manager` as an entry called `*session`.

This `*session` entry in the `credential manager` causes existing connections to other resources (network shares, database connections) to become invalid. Is there a way to tell Windows not to store the credentials?

I already know a solution, but this disables storage of credentials for the whole system: Setting the registry value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\DisableDomainCreds to 1`.

I would like to disable it only for my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove stored credentials
Use CredDelete() from Advapi32 [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374787(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374787%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
There is a new managed library in Windows 8 to deal with Windows vault
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1